# If a (linear) relation maps Lagrangian subspaces to Lagrangian subspaces, is it a Lagrangian relation?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $(U,\omega),(V,\rho)$ be symplectic vector spaces. We call a relation $U \to V$ a Lagrangian relation (also Lagrangian correspondence) if it is a Lagrangian subspace of $\overline U \oplus V$, where $\overline U$ is the conjugate symplectic vector space $(U,-\omega)$.

Lagrangian relations have the property that the composite (as relations) of two Lagrangian relations is again a Lagrangian relation. As any Lagrangian subspace of some space $U$ can be considered a Lagrangian relation $0 \to V$, this implies that Lagrangian relations map Lagrangian subspaces to Lagrangian subspaces. Does the converse hold?

That is, if a relation maps Lagrangian subspaces to Lagrangian subspaces, is it a Lagrangian relation?

Comment: Cross-posted at mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181219/if-a-linear-relation-maps-lagrangian-subspaces-to-lagrangian-subspaces-is-it.